# Is it possible to get system class by reflection in Android?

Tags: android, reflection, smartcard, sim-card, secure-element

I am interested in being able to communicate with SIM card in Android. I know that only system applications that have MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission or applications that have carrier priveledges on API >22 (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc) are able to call TelephonyManager.iccOpenLogicalChannel() method and perform further APDU exchange with SIM card. However there is a wonderful project that can add open interface to communicate with secure elements, sim cards etc called SEEK-for-android (https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool). The big problem is that you have to manually patch the OS yourself to use it.
And so while I was debugging an application I have seen this line in logcat output:

```
09-20 12:27:35.613 14942-14954/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1574)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.hasIccCard(ITelephony.java:3922)
    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.uiccterminal.UiccTerminal$TerminalServiceImplementation.isCardPresent(UiccTerminal.java:432)
    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service.Terminal.isCardPresent(Terminal.java:497)
    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service.Terminal.initializeAccessControl(Terminal.java:242)
    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service.Terminal$InitialiseTask.doInBackground(Terminal.java:121)
    at org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service.Terminal$InitialiseTask.doInBackground(Terminal.java:109)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

You can see org.simalliance.openmobileapi.* classes in the stacktrace. So it seems that my device (Samsung galaxy J2 - SM-G532F) actually HAS this patch applied to OS! Now my question is: can I somehow use them? I have tried to instanciate it by calling `Class.forName("org.simalliance.openmobileapi.uiccterminal.UiccTerminal")`
but I had no success and received ClassNotFoundException. So is it possible to instanciate and use those classes? Maybe I am missing something? Thank you in advance

Comment: If reflection doesn't grab it, it hasn't been made publicly accessible, so you can't use it.

Comment: Can you say what are you trying to achieve? Are you looking for specific classes and their usages or you just want to exchange any APDU with Sim card? Do you want to support some group of devices or just playing with your own phone for now?